# add columns to my Opencart 2.1.0.1 admin product list

Tags: database, opencart, helper, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I want to add columns to my product list. Now there are the options model, product name, picture of product and price, but i want more options like SKU and a column price+tax.

Is this possible by adjusting the file product_list.tpl or something like that?

Something like [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhJh9.jpg)

Comment: Which options you want to add to product listing page? Mention those fields so that I can help you in more better way.

Comment: Options like purchase price, price+tax, EAN code, SKU. Is that posible?

Comment: Yes it is possible to show it in listing page, but then your listing page will not look so much good.

Comment: is it posible to tel me how to do it? or show me

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. But you need to modify `admin/controller/catalog/product.php` file. In which you have to make changes in `getlist()` method. And modify `view/catalog/product_list.tpl` file for changes to be visible. You can also make changes in `model/catalog/product.php` file if you want to add new sorting methods for your newly added fields.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few free extensions showing up for adding columns to admin products list.  Be weary though, as Ved Pandya mentioned, it can be cramped and not actually be useful so use sparingly.

I'm guessing, the extensions in this instance should work from 2.0.3.1 but it's a trial and error.